Azure Document Translator for scanned and native pdf
I am using azure document translator service for translating pdf.Some of my pdf's are scanned and some are native pdf. The below code I am using for translation.
#  import libraries
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.translation.document import DocumentTranslationClient

# create variables for your resource key, custom endpoint, sourceUrl, targetUrl, and targetLanguage
key = '{your-api-key}'
endpoint = '{your-document-translation-endpoint}'
sourceUri = '<your-container-sourceUrl>'
targetUri = '<your-container-targetUrl>'
targetLanguage = '<target-language-code>'


# initialize a new instance of the DocumentTranslationClient object to interact with the asynchronous Document Translation feature
client = DocumentTranslationClient(endpoint, AzureKeyCredential(key))

# include source and target locations and target language code for the begin translation operation
poller = client.begin_translation(sourceUri, targetUri, targetLanguage)
result = poller.result()

print('Status: {}'.format(poller.status()))
print('Created on: {}'.format(poller.details.created_on))
print('Last updated on: {}'.format(poller.details.last_updated_on))
print(
    'Total number of translations on documents: {}'.format(
        poller.details.documents_total_count
    )
)

print('\nOf total documents...')
print('{} failed'.format(poller.details.documents_failed_count))
print('{} succeeded'.format(poller.details.documents_succeeded_count))

for document in result:
    print('Document ID: {}'.format(document.id))
    print('Document status: {}'.format(document.status))
    if document.status == 'Succeeded':
        print('Source document location: {}'.format(document.source_document_url))
        print(
            'Translated document location: {}'.format(document.translated_document_url)
        )
        print('Translated to language: {}\n'.format(document.translated_to))
    else:
        print(
            'Error Code: {}, Message: {}\n'.format(
                document.error.code, document.error.message
            )
        )

The above code is working fine when entire document is scanned or native but
I noticed that some of my pdf are having few pages scanned and few pages are native. In this case the document translator is not translating the scanned pages from that pdf.How to translate this type of pdfs.

You can use Azure’s OCR capabilities (e.g., Azure Computer Vision’s OCR feature) to extract text from the scanned pages before sending the PDF for translation. Once the OCR process is complete, you can combine the extracted text with the native pages for translation.After extracting the text from scanned pages, pass it to the Document Translator or use Text Translation services to translate it.Combine the translated content (both native and OCR-extracted text) into a new PDF, preserving the structure of the original document.
